Assert an error for a class initialization in Vitest
I have the following Vitest test:
it("should throw an error if the config file is not found but the path is valid", () => {
    expect(new Config("./tests/etech-ui.config.ts")).toThrowError();
  });

When I run the test command I get an error:
 FAIL  packages/etech-ui-utils/src/tests/Config.spec.ts > parseConfig > should throw an error if the config file is not found but the path is valid
AssertionError: expected Config{} to be a function
 ❯ packages/etech-ui-utils/src/tests/Config.spec.ts:26:54
     24| 
     25|   it("should throw an error if the config file is not found but the path is valid", () => {
     26|     expect(new Config("./tests/etech-ui.config.ts")).toThrowError();
       |                                                      ^
     27|   });

How can I achieve this functionality with a class. Why doesn't expect work?
Here is the relevant parts of my class definition. getConfigContents is where the error should be thrown.
export default class Config {
  private config: ConfigT | ConfigT[];
  constructor(path: string) {
    this.getConfigContents(path);
  }

  public async getConfigContents(path: string): Promise<ConfigT[] | ConfigT> {
    const pathRegex = /^(\/?(\.{1,2}\/)*[a-zA-Z0-9\-.]+)+$/;

    if (!pathRegex.test(path)) {
      throw new Error("The path to the etech.config.ts file is invalid.");
    }

    let foundValidPath = false;
    let configExtension = "";

    let i = 0;

    while (i < path.split(".").length + 1) {
      if (i >= path.split(".").length && !foundValidPath) {
        throw new Error("Your etech-ui.config file must end in .ts, .js, .mjs, .cjs, .mts, or .cts.");
      }

      if (
        path.split(".")[i] === "ts" ||
        path.split(".")[i] === "js" ||
        path.split(".")[i] === "mjs" ||
        path.split(".")[i] === "cjs" ||
        path.split(".")[i] === "mts" ||
        path.split(".")[i] === "cts"
      ) {
        console.log(path.split(".")[i]);
        foundValidPath = true;
        configExtension = path.split(".")[i];
      }

      i++;
    }

    try {
      await readFile(path, "utf8");
    } catch (err: any) {
      if (err.code === "ENOENT") {
        throw new Error("Could not find the etech.config.ts file.");
      }
    }

    this.config = await import(path);
    return this.config;
  }



Wrap it in a function.

@segFault edited my code to: const init = () => {       new Config("./tests/etech-ui.config.ts");     };     expect(init()).toThrowError(); And am now getting an error AssertionError: expected undefined to be a function  ❯ packages/etech-ui-utils/src/tests/Config.spec.ts:29:20      27|       new Config("./tests/etech-ui.config.ts");      28|     };      29|     expect(init()).toThrowError();        |                    ^      30|   });
